# How to clone the panel control to the same form dynamically in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, controls, panel

My need is to generate the copy of existing panel under the same panel in my form

I have written some code that would do my desired work but it's not going to work according to my needs, but It destroy the main panel and generate a copy, but I don't want to destroy first one, I want to keep all the panels...

This is the function that I've called at button "+" click event

```
Friend Function AddNewPanel() As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        Dim Pnl As New System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        Pnl = MediPanel  'This is the main panel that I want to copy
        Pnl.Top = 500
        'Pnl.Left = 100        
        ParentPanel.Controls.Add(Pnl)  'ParentPanel in which I want to generate a copy
        Return Pnl
    End Function
```

[This is what I exactly want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUgcy.png) but [This is actually happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKOML.png)

So, I want to generate copy of panel as I press "+" button and also earlier panels should not be destroyed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a new control dynamically. When your form loads, set a tag to your button indicating the bottom position of the original panel.

```
button1.tag = Medipanel.Bottom
```

When you click the + button

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

   Dim new_panel As New Panel
   With new_panel
     .Location = New Point(Medipanel.Left, Cint(button1.tag) + 5)
     .Size = New Size (Medipanel.Width, Medipanel.Height)
     ....
   End With

   Dim some_label = New Label
   With some_label
    .AutoSize = True
    .Name = "label"
    .Location = New Point(0, 0)  ''' Position in the new panel
    .Text = "Some Text" 
   End With
   new_panel.Controls.Add(some_label)

   Dim some_button as New Button
   With some_button
        .Tag = "some value" '''' A way to Identify the button if clicked
        ....
        ....
        AddHandler some_button.click, AddressOf some_button_click 
        '''' The Sub that determines what happens when that button is clicked.
   End With

   ....
   ....     

   ParentPanel.Controls.Add(new_panel)

   button1.tag = new_panel.bottom '''' Set the bottom position of the last panel added.

End Sub
```

When the new button is clicked:

```
Private Sub some_button_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

   Dim sending_button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
   Dim ref As String = DirectCast(sending_button.Tag, String)

   ''''Perform your stuff here

End Sub
```

This will only add a new control and not destroy old ones.